# If Statement and selecting a row

Tags: mysql, if-statement, view, sql-update

Using MYSQL.

Trying to write an IF Statement.

Table name: Erreur
Columns names: Company, ID, Published, Type, Erreur_type, etc

```
select * from erreur
where Erreur_type IS NOT NULL
IF Erreur_type = 1 Then SET Published = NULL
ELSE Erreur_type = 2 Then SET Type = 'Ordinaire'
ELSE Erreur_type = 3 Then SET TYPE = 'Extraordinaire'
END IF;
```

My question is, do I need:
-To select a row or I can use this code on multiple rows at ones?

Comment: Are you trying to update the table, or you want the TYPE as string in select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want selecting the result then

```
select 
     IF (Erreur_type = 1 , NULL,'your_else') as publised 
    , case when Erreur_type = 2 then 'Ordinaire'
            when  Erreur_type = 3 then  'Extraordinaire' 
    end AS Type
from erreur
where Erreur_type IS NOT NULL
```

otherwise if you want change the values in db the use update and set

```
update  erreur
set publised = case when  Erreur_type = 1 THEN null else  publised end, 
    Erreur_type = case when Erreur_type = 2 then 'Ordinaire'
                when  Erreur_type = 3 then  'Extraordinaire' 
        end 
where Erreur_type IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think you are missing an `else` portion in your `if` statement -- `if(expr, true, false)`...